# Filter params before update error, cant edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to edit params before update so if password is not typed it will not be required

Here is my controller

```
def update
    @professional = Professional.find(params[:id])
    request.params[:professional].delete("password") if params[:professional][:password].blank?
    request.params[:professional].delete("password_confirmation") if params[:professional][:password_confirmation].blank?
    puts params
    if @professional.update_attributes(params[:professional])
        redirect_to professionals_path
    else
        render action: "edit"
    end
end
```

Here is my server reaction

I set it to print params after remove the password key

```
"{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"put",
"authenticity_token"=>"AdJya2kGwbuQZ/VYRGnvBRJvWAw40B766gfObQidmdY=", 
"professional"=>{"name"=>"Prometheus Deimos Dardanos", 
"role"=>"Admin", 
"email"=>"prometheus@mail.com"}, 
"commit"=>"Salvar", "action"=>"update", 
"controller"=>"professionals", "locale"=>"pt-BR", "id"=>"1"}
```

Then the request get invalidate as POST and get redirected as PUT and the password key gets back in params.

```
cache: [POST /profissionais/1] invalidate, pass
Started PUT "/profissionais/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-25 11:27:16 -0300
Processing by ProfessionalsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AdJya2kGwbuQZ/VYRGnvBRJvWAw40B766gfObQidmdY=", "professional"=>{"name"=>"Prometheus Deimos Dardanos", "role"=>"Admin", "email"=>"prometheus@mail.com", 
             "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Salvar", "locale"=>"pt-BR", "id"=>"1"}
Professional Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "professionals".* FROM "professionals" WHERE "professionals"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Professional Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "professionals".* FROM "professionals" WHERE "professionals"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction"
```

As you may see, when I print the params it doesn't have the key password.

Comment: Try with `params[:professional].delete("password") if params[:professional]["password"].blank?` or the opposite: `params[:professional].delete(:password) if params[:professional][:password].blank?` -- Not sure if the params is considered as a HashWithIndifferentAccess

Comment: my code success remove password key pro params, but it as you may see...but it "magically" appears back on PUT requisition. it's iam editing another params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your controller to:

```
def update
  @professional = Professional.find(params[:id])
  request.params[:professional].delete("password") if params[:professional][:password].blank?
  request.params[:professional].delete("password_confirmation") if params[:professional]      [:password_confirmation].blank?
  puts params

  if @professional.update_attributes(params[:professional])
    redirect_to professionals_path
  else
    puts @professional.errors
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
```

So that you can understand why it's not updating the resource correctly.

Comment: I added you command, and i get password required error, probably because the password key appears back in params